# Trying to make a loop that checks all of the positions in a list. What I am writing only returns true or false for the first position

Tags: python, function, if-statement

So the idea is to create a function that checks the length of each word in a string. For a given number, x, if all the words are greater than or equal to x, return True. Otherwise, return False. For instance, if my sentence is "He wants a new computer" and x = 2, it should return false, because "a" is only one letter. "He eats apples" would return True, because no words are less than 2. My code only seems to run through the first word, and not through the rest of them. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong? I am using python. Thanks!

```
def x_length_words(sentence, x): 
  sentence_list = sentence.split()
  for i in sentence_list: 
    if len(i) >= x: 
      return True
    else: 
      return False
print(x_length_words("i like apples", 2))
# should print False, prints False
print(x_length_words("he likes apples", 2))
# should print True, prints True
print(x_length_words("He wants a car", 2))
#should print, False, prints True
```

Answer (score 3):

you should only return `True` if you have checked all the words (and not if you just have found one that is longer than `x`):

```
def x_length_words(sentence, x):
    sentence_list = sentence.split()
    for i in sentence_list:
        if len(i) < x:
            return False
    return True
```

the shorter version would just be (using [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)):

```
def x_length_words(sentence, x):
    return all(len(i) >= x for i in sentence.split())
```

Comment: Could you explain why my code stopped at the first item in the list, and didn't check the rest of them?

Comment: in the `"He wants a car"` example you test the length of `He`, which is `>= 2`, so you return `True`. you never have a look at any of the other words. add a `print(i)` statement before the `if` clause and you will see that happens. or better yet: run the code in a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that by using `return` you are 'quitting' your defined function `x_length_words`). Try instead:

```
def x_length_words(sentence, x): 
  sentence_list = sentence.split()
  for i in sentence_list: 
    if len(i) >= x: 
      pass
    else: 
      return False
  return True

print(x_length_words("i like apples", 2))
# prints False
print(x_length_words("he likes apples", 2))
# prints True
print(x_length_words("He wants a car", 2))
# prints False
```

This is a very minimal alteration to your function, it would be more elegant to remove the "else" statement all together:

```
def x_length_words(sentence, x): 
  sentence_list = sentence.split()
  for i in sentence_list: 
    if len(i) < x: 
      return False
  return True

print(x_length_words("i like apples", 2))
# prints False
print(x_length_words("he likes apples", 2))
# prints True
print(x_length_words("He wants a car", 2))
# prints False
```

Comment: Ah ok.  So I understand the idea, and I can see clearly why your alteration to my original code works. In your more elegant solution... would the computer run through the loop first, and then continue on to "return True" once it didn't find something to return in the loop? Am I thinking about that right?

Comment: yes your understanding is correct! In my solution, the computer runs through the sentence and checks if ```len(i) < x```, if that is true then the function stops and ```False``` is returned. However if it finds that the ```if``` statement is false, it just goes through the next iteration of the loop and so on. If it gets to the end of the sentence and hasn't found the ```if``` statement to be true, then the ```return True``` is called, because this is outside the ```for``` loop.

Comment: great explanation. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**[Solved]:** You can use this one line function.

> ```
> def x_length_words(sentence, x): 
>   return x <=  min(map(len, sentence.split(" ")))
> ```

```
print(x_length_words("i like apples", 2))
#print False (ok)
print(x_length_words("he likes apples", 2))
#print True(ok)
print(x_length_words("He wants a car", 2))
#print, False (ok)
```

**[EDIT]:** A second proposed solution as you just write it. so when you call the **return** you get exit completely from the function, and then you can't loop to the rest of sentence.

```
def x_length_words(sentence, x): 
  sentence_list = sentence.split()
  for i in sentence_list: 
    if len(i) < x: 
      return False
  return True    

  
print(x_length_words("i like apples", 2))
# should print False, prints False
print(x_length_words("he likes apples", 2))
# should print True, prints True
print(x_length_words("He wants a car", 2))
#should print, False, prints False
```